# ¿Cómo concatenar dos arreglos en python?

Tags: array, python-3.7

tengo un arreglo en el que quiero guardar el contenido de otro arreglo, pero quiero guardar lo que tiene en varias posiciones hasta llegar a la coma, es que recibo caracteres y quiero juntar las palabras que forman esos caracteres separandolas por comas, este es mi código:

```
import numpy as np

cadena=['c','a','s','a',',','p','e','r','r','o']
cadena2=[]
tamañocadena = len(cadena)
posicion = 0

for n in cadena:
    if cadena[n].value == ",":
        posicion = posicion + 1
        print("entre")
    cadena2[posicion].append(cadena2[posicion] + cadena[n])

print(cadena2)
```

Pero me da el siguiente error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Aclarar que es una lista, no un arreglo.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque estás mezclando arrays con diccionarios. Además, el for va metiendo en "n" los valores de la cadena ('c', 'a', 's', etc.) no la posición.

Por ejemplo en:

`if cadena[n].value == ",":`

deberías poner:

`if n == ",":`

Otro error que tienes es que estás intentando usar un elemento inexistente:

`cadena2[posicion].append()`

El array `cadena2` está vacío así que te va a dar un error de índice no existente. Sería algo así lo que deberías hacer:

´cadena2.append()`

De todos modos no consigo entender bien la lógica de lo que quieres hacer ¿puedes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Hola! lo que sucede es que dentro de un arreglo guardo varias palabras carácter por carácter y lo que necesito es juntar las palabras que forman esos caracteres, por ejemplo en arreglo 1 guardo: 'Q','U','E','S','O', entonces quiero juntar en un arreglo esos caracteres para que en una sola posición diga 'QUESO', y como las palabras que guardo carácter por carácter van separadas con comas (','), por eso quiero indicarle que a partir de esa coma pase a la siguiente posición del arreglo para guardar la siguiente palabra.

Comment: PD: Ya probe con n == "," y me da el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

El problema te está pasando en esta parte:

```
for n in cadena:
    if cadena[n].value == ",":
```

cuando dices `for n in cadena`, recorrerá tu lista devolviendote cada elemento de esta, es decir, para la lista `['c', 'a', 's', 'a', ',', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'o']`:

En la primera vuelta `n` valdrá `'c'`, en la segunda `n` valdrá `'a`', en la tercera `n` valdrá `'s'`, etc.
Al poner `if cadena[n]...` lo que está haciendo en la primera vuelta es `cadena['c']`, de ahí que te diga que para acceder a la lista, los índices deben ser números o slices, por ejemplo `cadena[0]`, `cadena[3]`, etc.

Una manera de resolver este problema (aunque surgirá otro más adelante) sería sustituir esas líneas por:

```
for n in cadena:
    if n == ",":
```

De todas formas, por lo que he visto en tus comentarios que quieres conseguir, todo este código se puede cambiar por:

```
cadena = ['c', 'a', 's', 'a', ',', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'o']
nuevaCadena = ''.join(cadena).split(',')
print(nuevaCadena)  # Esto devuelve ['casa', 'perro']
```

Primero unes todos los elementos de la lista con 'nada' `''.join(cadena)`, obteniendo una cadena de texto `'casa,perro'` y luego la divides por la coma `split(',')` obteniendo una lista.

Comment: Tambien podrías usar `cadena.replace(',','')` que da el mismo resultado que `"".join(candena.split(','))`

Comment: No debo haber entendido muy bien cómo dices de hacerlo @DanteS, en este caso `cadena` es una lista de caracteres, así que `cadena.replace` daría error. Ten en cuenta que yo el `.split(',')` se lo he aplicado a `''.join(cadena)` que no es exactamente igual que `"".join(candena.split(','))` que es lo que me has puesto tú.

Comment: Ups, mi error, lei mal!